# $f \in L^p \iff |f|^p \in L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I want to show explicitly that $f \in L^p \iff |f|^p \in L^1$. It looks quite trivial, is it so or am I missing some point?

Comment: It could be that $f$ is not even measurable but $\lvert f \rvert ^p$ is in $L^1$. Consider some non-measurable set $E$ and define $f$ to have value $1$ on $E$ and have value $-1$ elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.

$f \in L^P$ means $\int |f|^p <\infty$. But then this is precisely what it means for $|f|^p$ to be $L^1$.